# Gnuplot on Overleaf

Tags: latex, gnuplot

I'm using gnuplottex on Overleaf. I want to crate an heatmaps of data stored in a file, where the columns are "x y z":

```
  -0.5  95.5  0.00000
  -0.5  96.5  0.00000
  -0.5  97.5  0.00000
  -0.5  98.5  0.00000
  -0.5  99.5  0.00000
  -0.5 100.5  0.00000
   0.5  -0.5  0.00000
   0.5   0.5  0.02658
   0.5   1.5  0.05317
   0.5   2.5  0.07975
   0.5   3.5  0.10633
   0.5   4.5  0.13288
   0.5   5.5  0.15940
```

I try to use the following code, but the pdf generated by overleaf has only the axis and there isn't any color plot.

```
\begin{gnuplot}[scale=0.9]
set pm3d map
set dgrid3d                             
splot "ElectricPotential.txt" using 1:2:3
\end{gnuplot}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To quote the `gnuplottex` documentation about the default `latex` terminal:

> This is a terminal that offers only basic support, as you won’t be able to (easily) use colours.

So just set another terminal which can deal with colours:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{gnuplottex}

\begin{document}

\begin{gnuplot}[scale=0.9,terminal=cairolatex]
set pm3d map
set dgrid3d                             
splot "ElectricPotential.txt" using 1:2:3
\end{gnuplot}


\end{document}
```

and here the corresponding overleaf project:

https://www.overleaf.com/read/vfdssqvdkyxv

[image]